# How to power 5 x 1.5v dc motors from uk mains

Tags: dc-motor

I’m an art student with little knowledge about this topic, but I’m needing to power 5 x 1.5v dc motors from the same power source, preferably from uk mains.

I have tried using a adjustable mains converter and a daisy chain and connecting them through that. But I’m wondering if that is safe to do so as the motors will need to run for a long period of time.

Thanks

Comment: Are your motors connected in series or in parallel?  "Daisy chained" is not a typical expression used to describe electrical circuits.  Check wikipedia if you don't know the difference between series circuits and parallel circuits.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 7.5Vdc power supply if connected in series. (Daisy chained)
Or you could connect them all in parallel using a 1.5Vdc power supply.

Knowing what you are using them for would help. Is the load on the motors changing? Etc.

The main thing is knowing what is the current draw for each motor is, so you can make sure your power supply has enough capacity to power the system.
Power = Current X Voltage - in Watts

You should not have to worry about safety, especially once the current draw to the motors should be, and adding a fuse to be sure. Example: if the motors draw 1 Amp, put in a 2 Amp fuse. Or a 1.5 amp slow blow. Motors have a high start up current, so I would recommend the slow blow fuse.

Comment: I feel like there could be problems putting multiple motors in series, especially if the loads aren't close to balanced. I could be entirely wrong, though.

Comment: You can't connect motors in series unless the spindles are connected together. Motors with different loads will attempt to draw different level of current ....net effect will be to see the motor with the most load will stall.

Comment: In terms of the load I’ve attached a small pieces on wire hanging down from the shaft no more than a meter in length to each motor. I am using a daisy chain at the moment does that mean that they are on a series or in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Daisy chained would imply you have them in series.
@Jack Creasey is correct in that it would be best to have them in parallel.

If you are not really loading the motors, you could get away with your series configuration. Better practice is parrallel.

What are you using to power these motors? Actually I guess that is your original question.
For simplicity I would use a 6Vdc wall supply or battery, depending on what you want, and then using a LM317 voltage regulator to bring the (motors in parallel down to 1.5 to 1.6V. The minimum voltage out For the LM317 (TO-220) package is 1.25V. So you would have no problem connecting them in parallel with that adjustable regulator.

You could use a 9V or 12V supply as well, it would just be less efficient.
With more power wasted at the regulator. You should measure the current needed for 1 motor under load, then calculate the total power needed, so you start out with a power supply that can handle the load.
If you do this, and tell me the power, I can send you a circuit to fit your needs.